# Embedding html5 video with opengraph on facebook

Tags: html, facebook, youtube, facebook-opengraph

I have built a web site for our student tv station and the concept is pretty similar to youtube. We would like for our videos to be playable directly in facebook when shared, with the videos themselves still hosted on our server and our stats being updated.

The player on the site uses videojs and is all working with the html5 video tag. There is also an embeddable version of the player that can run in an iframe. Ideally I'd like this to be used on facebook but don't think it's possible. This is what I've attempted at the moment with the og:video:type value set to text/html and og:video set to the embeddable player url and it doesn't appear to work. [Here is an example page](https://www.la1tv.co.uk/player/109/220), and [here is the embeddable player for it](https://embed.la1tv.co.uk/109/220).

The only other ways I've seen is to specify a url to the video file, or a url to a flash player.

All of our videos are rendered at different qualities/resolutions and on our site and embeddable player there is a quality selection bar that changes the video url in the player. However it looks like with opengraph and facebook there is no way of giving it the urls to the different qualities or having the user pick the one they want on facebook, meaning we're stuck with forcing everyone to watch at one of the qualities. Is this right?

So then the only other option that appears to be available is building a custom flash player which has quality selection built into it. From what I can tell this is what youtube is doing. Is this the only option though because I don't want to build a custom flash player for Facebook to then decide in a few months that they're not supporting flash anymore?

I realise similar questions have been asked already but I couldn't find a definite answer and some of them were over a year old.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some progress on this issue?
And generally, Do you have achieved your video playback in facebook? Your site and idea so good!)

Comment: Thanks. No as far as I can tell creating my own flash player that suits our needs appears to be the only way at the moment. Would really like to have a definite answer though from someone or link to some documentation saying this.

Comment: The html5 youtube player is now embedded in facebook, and I am using the same tags, but it is is not working for me and I am getting an error message that doesn't make sense. I have opened another question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28815838/1048589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook is currently trialing iframes with YouTube. Hopefully the support will be rolled out to everyone soon.

More info at this question: [Embedding video player html5 iframe in facebook share like YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815838/embedding-video-player-html5-iframe-in-facebook-share-like-youtube)